# Can't mass assign protected attributes in has_many belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

Am using rails 3.2.13 and I have models for two entities like so

```
class Restaurant < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible  :description, :menu, :restaurant_name
  has_many :cuisines
end

class Cuisine < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :cuisine_name, :restaurant_id
  attr_accessible :cuisine_ids
  belongs_to :restaurant
end
```

The controller action for creating a restaurant look like this

I have a form for creating a restaurant using simple form gem like so

```
<%= simple_form_for @restaurant do |f| %>
<%= f.input :restaurant_name %>
<%= f.input :description %>
<%= f.input :menu %>
<%= f.association :cuisines, label_method: :cuisine_name %>
<%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Am basically suppose to chose from a group of cuisines which simple form helps with. However when i select the cuisine and try to create the restaurant. It brings back the error.

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error at /restaurants
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: cuisine_ids
```

As you can see in the model. I placed attribute as accessible but it didn't work. I even tried the singular version cuisine_id with no luck. I have no idea what is wrong? I would prefer not to tamper with the rails defaults for protecting against mass assignment. Any clues?

Comment: @ShadowWizard I'd moved my comment to an answer after switching devices.

Comment: @ShadowWizard :p *lol*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Cuisine` doesn't have `cuisine_ids`, `Restaurant` does.

Move your `attr_accessible :cuisine_ids` into the `Restaurant` model.